# GPG smartcards handling 4096-bit keys

Tags: gnupg, smartcard, pam, enigmail

are there smartcards that handle 4096-bit keys supported both by GPG and Enigmail (PAM would be additional benefit)? Preferably on USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quoting somebody else here:

> Actually the OpenPGP Card / Crypto
>   Stick can handle 4k keys as well but
>   GnuPG is not able to handle 4k keys of
>   smart cards. To use 4k keys either
>   GnuPG needs to be patched

4096 support in smart cards is relatively rare, the common size is currently 2048 for RSA (cards do have EC support though). The [CryptoStick](http://www.privacyfoundation.de/crypto_stick/crypto_stick_english/) claims to support 3k RSA keys but apparently only because that's the limit for GnuPG, the card should be able to do more.

Comment: Any information where can I find a patch?

Comment: None that I know of. Are you sure you need 4k keys?

Comment: Hi there. I've patched this, see the last thread of http://goo.gl/gtuoG :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can get cryptocards that support 4096-bit keys, but as long as they're a PKCS11 smartcard, you'll find they'll work with most things. I formatted an unused Aladdin eToken as a standard PKCS11 token, and had it working with OpenSSH and Firefox. Getting it working with GPG, Enigmail and PAM would be trivial, I suspect.

Have a look at some of the stuff that uses [OpenSC](http://www.opensc-project.org) - that tends to support many different kinds of tokens and cryptocards.

Answer (score 0):

The information in the previous answers is over seven years old now; [the OpenPGP smart card has supported 4096-bit RSA keys for several years now](https://www.floss-shop.de/en/security-privacy/smartcards/), and also now supports ECC.

Comment: Yubikey Series 5 does support 4096 RSA as well (https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-5-overview/)

Comment: What is the corresponding command to create a 4096 bit RSA key on an OpenPGP card?  gpg(2) --card-edit; admin; generate --algo=????
I tried different values but everything results in 2048 bit key. Using Kleopatra I was able to generate 3072 bit keys on the card.

I am using OpenPGP Cards V3.3, gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27 and a ReinerSCT comfort card reader  with latest driver from Ubuntu repository.  Copy 4096 bit to the card is possible. I remember that several years ago there has been an issue to to some card readers limiting the key length when creating keys directly on the card.